# Complete / Progress events aren't firing for Image control with embedded content

Tags: apache-flex, image, mxml, flex3

I've got the following MXML tag:

```
<mx:Image id="image" width="100%" height="100%" 
              source="@Embed('../assets/Test.swf')" 
              complete="completeHandler(event)" 
              progress="progressHandler(event)"/>
```

But for some reason my completeHandler / progressHandler functions aren't being called. The reason I need the complete event is because I want to manipulate the bitmap data once the image has loaded. In creationComplete the bitmap data is still null. Why aren't these events firing?

**Edit:** The asset is correctly showing in my application - so I know the asset is in the right location (the embed guarantees that at compile time anyway).

Comment: Does the content appear properly in your app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using an embedded asset, the width / height properties are available immediately on the source object:

```
var mySource:Object = new embeddedClass();
m_myWidth = mySource.width;
m_myHeight = mySource.height;
m_image = new Image();
m_image.source = mySource;
```

So, you have to create an instance of the source first, then set the source on your image object.

Answer (score 0):

Check your asset path. Most probably, the swf is not at the right path or is not getting copied to an `assets` folder in the debug-build/release-build directory.

Answer (score 0):

So, you just have to add the Event.COMPLETE listener to the loader.contentLoaderInfo directly instead of to the loader.  I can't believe this isn't int he docs.

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be the expected behavior here!

From the documentation:

> The progress event is not guaranteed to be dispatched. The complete event may be received, without any progress events being dispatched. This can happen when the loaded content is a local file.

So I think this part can explain why no progress events are being caught in your example.

> Dispatched when content loading is complete. Unlike the complete event, this event is dispatched for all source types.
>   Note that for content loaded via Loader, both ready and complete events are dispatched.
>   For other source types such as embeds, only ready is dispatched.

It clearly says that you should listen for READY events instead of COMPLETE when dealing with embedded sources ;)